# Increment through array across daily scheduled jobs

Tags: arrays, powershell, jobs

Is it possible to have the arguments in a daily scheduled job increment each day? I have an array of values and I want to run one job per value, spread out so that the jobs occur once a day.

This is my code so far:

```
$dailyTrigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "11:00 AM"
$option = New-ScheduledJobOption -StartIfOnBattery -StartIfIdle -WakeToRun -IdleTimeout "10:00:00"

Register-ScheduledJob -Name $JobName -FilePath $ScriptToRun -Trigger $dailyTrigger -ScheduledJobOption $option
```

I was planning on using `Register-ScheduledJob`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter, but from what I've seen there would be no way to pass a different value to each daily instance of the job. Is there some way I could store which element of the array is next so that the jobs could reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to persist a counter between job runs is to store the value in the registry:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\foo' -Name 'Job1' -Value ($counter + 1)
```

and read it on the next run:

```
$counter = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\foo').Job1
```